# Calculate column-wise percentages on a pivot table

Tags: pyspark, pivot

Let's create a pyspakr dataframe using the following csv:

```
desc,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,B10,B11
Other,111957.0,35293.0,225852.0,35110.0,1023680.0,448736.0,256473.0,269856.0,306668.0,8807.0,89551.0
Down,575614.0,203186.0,0.0,125056.0,0.0,766086.0,1157311.0,11127.0,88741.0,31603.0,300733.0
Up,0.0,0.0,1953645.0,0.0,346423.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
Same,2948065.0,730113.0,33121.0,668868.0,5451224.0,4485121.0,30780025.0,1977361.0,5295598.0,217697.0,1790024.0
Old,186596.0,88257.0,0.0,36842.0,2173626.0,240619.0,0.0,2770.0,2212560.0,9865.0,121045.0
New,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3148.0,0.0,97252.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
```

It's created by using pivot on a dataframe:

```
y = x.groupby('desc').pivot('prev_segment').sum('cust_count')
```

What I now want is to convert the values into percentages for each `B*` column. The percentage is derived from summing up all the values in the column and then dividing each cell by the total. So the columns total up to 100%

Will be grateful if someone can give me an easy way to do this, preferably as part of the agg function in the pivot itself. So instead of `sum('cust_count')` perhaps there is another easier way to give me resultant dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function.
Divide each row with the outcome of the sum of the column. multiply that by 100 and round to 0 decimal places. colRegex will help you select only rows that have B.

```
df.select("desc",*[round(col(x)/sum(x).over(Window.partitionBy())*100,0).astype('integer').alias(x) for x in df.select(df.colRegex("`^B.*`")).columns]).show()

+-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| desc| B1| B2| B3| B4| B5| B6| B7| B8| B9|B10|B11|
+-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|Other|  3|  3| 10|  4| 11|  8|  1| 12|  4|  3|  4|
| Down| 15| 19|  0| 14|  0| 13|  4|  0|  1| 12| 13|
|   Up|  0|  0| 88|  0|  4|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
| Same| 77| 69|  1| 77| 61| 75| 95| 87| 67| 81| 78|
|  Old|  5|  8|  0|  4| 24|  4|  0|  0| 28|  4|  5|
|  New|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
+-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any way to get the column besides using that regex. The column names are only a placeholder. So can I use a regex that gives me everything that is not named `desc`

Comment: Not sure I understood what you meant. However, lets try  `df.select("desc",*[round(col(x)/sum(x).over(Window.partitionBy())*100,0).astype('integer').alias(x) for x in df.columns if x!='desc']).show()`

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense. I am getting a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` All my columns except `desc` are `DoubleType`

Comment: Its the same if use even a single column `df.select("desc",*[round(F.col(x)/sum(x).over(Window.partitionBy())*100,0).astype('integer').alias(x) for x in ['B1']]).show()`

Comment: `ydfselect('desc',*[F.round(F.col(x)/F.sum(x).over(Window.partitionBy())*100, 2).alias(x) for x in y.columns if x!='desc'])` this finally worked. I think it was overloading the python round function so I had to be explicit

Comment: Are you able to accept the answer and upvote it? I gave you an upvote